# c unexpected output when recv from socket to a unsigned char array

Tags: arrays, c, sockets, websocket

I have the following packet payload from a websocket Im parsing in c.

```
81 82 ce 5d 4d ac bf 57
```

I received it with a unsigned char array like this.

```
unsigned char array[256];

recv(new_socket, array, sizeof(array),0);
```

But when i iterate over it to check it out it gets funky...

```
while(i != 256){

        printf("%x\n", array[i]);
        
        i++;
    }

#output:
81
82
ce
5d
4d
ac
bf
57
40
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
40

... more zeros and bad hexes
```

It looks like the first few are fine but then something starts adding nulls and random weird hexes to my buf. This seems simple to me but i'm new. Can you guys help me fix it?

Comment: recv() returns a value **use it!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard [recv function from Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html), the function returns a value of type `ssize_t` that specifies how many bytes it received.  You should look at the return value and only print that many bytes.  If you print more bytes than that, you are just printing uninitialized bytes from your array, so they could be anything.

You could make your output cleaner and help avoid undefined behavior by initializing your array with zeros when you define it:

```
unsigned char array[256] = {};
```

Comment: Thanks man very helpful. Just out of curiosity why are there random "uninitialized bytes" floating around my stack... Heres my best guess. When I imagine a piece of ram allocated for my program for security reasons I would expect a clean slate of 0s, all the stuff from the last program wiped away. but I may be wrong. Are these weird hex ints remnants of another program or am I being silly and its something else entirely.

Comment: @TaylorJohnson What's on the stack is whatever is left over from previous method calls and their parameters, local variables, and return addresses and base pointers.